# Menu with sitemap not showing subitems in all browsers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Can't get my menu to show any of my sub items.  It shows the arrow that there is a sub item but when i hover over they do not pop up.  And yes i did look at other questions on here.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
        Orientation="Horizontal">
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />



<siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Home">
<siteMapNode url="~/organizations/organizations.aspx" title="My Organization" />
<siteMapNode url="~/locations/locations.aspx" title="Locations" >
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="~/requests/landing.aspx" title="Request" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/requests/location.aspx" title="Location" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/requests/locationmanager.aspx" title="Location Manager"  />
  <siteMapNode url="~/requests/organization.aspx" title="Organization"  />
  <siteMapNode url="~/requests/organizationmanager.aspx" title="Organization Manager"  />
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="~/admin/landing.aspx" title="Admin" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/admin/categories/manage.aspx" title="Manage Categories"  />
  <siteMapNode url="~/admin/locationtypes/manage.aspx" title="Manage Location Types" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/admin/metadatatypes/manage.aspx" title="Manage Meta Data Types" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/admin/requests/manage.aspx" title="Manage Requests" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/admin/weekdaytemplates/manage.aspx" title="Manage Week Day Templates" />
</siteMapNode>
```

EDIT: Here is my firebug code

```
     <div>
<a style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;" href="#Menu1_SkipLink">Skip Navigation Links</a>
<div id="Menu1" style="float: left;">
<ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;" role="menubar">
<li class="static" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<li class="static" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<li class="static" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:5" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:11" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<a class="popout level2 static" href="/admin/landing.aspx" tabindex="-1">Admin</a>
<ul id="Menu1:submenu:11" class="level3 dynamic" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
<li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
<li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
<li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
<li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
<li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue could be JS, CSS, or any number of other things. You should be a bit more explicit about your scenario, and what you've tried so far to debug it.

Comment: I'm using the standard out of the box template.  I haven't changed any JS, or any CSS yet. I've tried messing with the staticdisplaylevels, the maxdynamic display levels and i've changed the format of the sitemap multiple times.  Currently i have it in the simplest form just to get it working.